# Max number of executor failures (120) reached getting in AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to run my spark job on AWS EMR for migration work (which is running fine on on-prem) but getting failed in AWS(after AWS changes) with below error

"Max number of executor failures (120) reached"

But it is working fine with reduced number of executor as 5 (Ideally we need 50 executor).

```
Dynamic allocation =  false
Executor number = 50
Executor memory = 30g
overhead = 3g
driver memory = 20g
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the reasons that the executors failed? You can find error messages in the driver's stderr log. Please see the "View log files archived to Amazon S3" section of the [View log files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html) page. It should be located in the first container's prefix.